# How to make checkbox checked by default in php

Tags: php, javascript

I am working in a form in which there are check boxes now i want to check one by default in admin panel which is checked by the user in fromt end while he submitted form.Form is same in both the panel but in admin panel the form is already filled with values entered by the user at the time of submitted in front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" <?php if($status=="admin") echo "checked=\"checked\""?>>
```

Comment: thanks it is really simple but i had no clue

Answer (score 1):

When creating the HTML you need to set the `checked` (or `checked="checked"` in XHTML) attribute of the `<input>` tag.